# automatic comma in textboxes

Tags: asp.net

Actually commas are perfectly executed in the text box. 12345=12,345
However my submit button is not functioning well when i am declaring the javascrip with my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductPrice" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength ="6" onkeyup ="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

here is my button code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile != null)
        {
            SaveProductPhoto();

            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                ProductName = txtProductName.Text,
                ProductImage = "~/ProductImages/" + uploadProductPhoto.FileName,
                ProductPrice = txtProductPrice.Text,
                ProductDescription = txtProductDescription.Text,
                CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue),
                TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductQuantity.Text)
            };
            k.AddNewProduct();
            ClearText();
            Label2.Text = "Product Added!";
            //Response.Redirect("AddNewProduct.aspx?alert=success");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please upload photo');</script>");
```

The code is finished ("Product Added" is showing up) however, the product is not actually added. its not in the database or anywhere. any tricks on this?

here is the k.AddNewProduct();

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddNewProduct]
(
@ProductName varchar(300),
@ProductPrice varchar(500),
@ProductImage varchar(500),
@ProductDescription varchar(1000),
@CategoryID int,
@ProductQuantity int
)

AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY

            Insert into products
            values
            (@ProductName,
            @ProductDescription,
            @ProductPrice,
            @ProductImage,
            @CategoryID,
            @ProductQuantity
            )

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT ('Error Occured')
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: What is the type of ProductPrice in the DB?

Comment: varchar sir @Idanb

Comment: Did you debug the `k.AddNewProduct()` to see whats going on there? You dont get any errors from the DB there?

Comment: its perfectly fine sir if i remove the onkey code on my asp textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have js by using simplified regex

```
function Comma(Num) {
var parts = Num.toString().split(".");
parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
return parts.join(".");
}
```

if you also need support for numbers with decimals then use the below code

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
var parts=n.toString().split(".");
return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```